# How see build statistics in maven?

Tags: maven

I there a way to see extended maven statitics in multi module project not only total build time for particular project, but time spent to plugins, total plugin time and plugin time per project, pure compile time, time for downloading dependencies/plugin/artifact?

Answer (score 3):

To some extent this is implemented by various `maven-interceptors/spies`; [Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org) has one that monitors execution time per plugin. I've used the [Maven Profiler](https://github.com/takari/maven-profiler) sometimes to look for hotspots in my builds. While I don't think it will do all the things you want it might be a starting point.

Example output from `Maven Profiler

```
process-test-classes 134ms
  org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-metadata:1.5.5 (default) 110ms
  org.sonatype.plugins:sisu-maven-plugin:1.1 (default) 23ms

test 11s 306ms
  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12 (default-test) 11s 306ms

package 1s 371ms
  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 (default-jar) 502ms
  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 (attach-descriptor) 869ms
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another profiler: https://github.com/jcgay/maven-profiler/

Some improvements over takari:

- works with multiple threads
- html and json reports